# Sed Usage to update GRUB file

Tags: 16.04, grub2, scripts, text-processing, sed

I am new to using sed but quickly learning to love it for its general flexibility in automation. I am looking to run a script with various security controls every time I deploy a new system, and part of that requires me to lock down the GRUB. I am looking to unlock the general Ubuntu option from the GRUB menu so anyone can use it after that without a password, while keeping everything else password protected.

that being said, I am looking to search the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file for a specific line and add --unrestricted to that option. ( We only use 16.04.03 so all systems would theoretically have the same file upon install )

The line in the file is:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-2aa7ed2c-67a7-42d5-84fb-0ddab74c5dd0' {
```

And I want it to look like:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-2aa7ed2c-67a7-42d5-84fb-0ddab74c5dd0' {
```

I know sed -i is for in place editing and s/ should search. But beyond that I am lost on the syntax here to make it actually do what we need. As far as I can tell, that positioning of --unrestricted is needed as I believe it would be easier if we didnt have to have such a long search, but again I am new to sed and unsure. Could someone help me with this sed insertion? Preferably also explain to me why different syntax goes where it does, so I know for the future.

Comment: you are not supposed to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg. It will be replace with every sudo update-grub which will be auto run with kernel updates or grub updates. Probably better to turn off most of the grub scripts and create your own entry in 40_custom exactly as you want. You only need 00_header & 05_debian-theme and a custom 40_custom with your desired entries.

Comment: Do you have a link to this anywhere? I must have found something for an older version or something. I want to know how to do it properly.

Comment: @oldfred this link recommends what I was going to do or to edit the 10_linux file. So I went with the one that was listed first thinking it would be the better process, it doesnt mention what you stated, so should I go with the other?

Comment: Old thread when grub2 first came out: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8191211#post8191211 Also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: @oldfred As far as I can see, none of those links tell me how to unrestrict ONE entry in the GRUB menu. And linux_10 doesn't exist where my link says it does (empty file)

Comment: The link mistakenly put /etc/grub/10_linux when it actually is /etc/grub.d/10_linux that generates the script to be ran with grub updates. This is a permanent solution where what I originally talked about would be temporary. Thank you @oldfred for pointing this out and prompting further research!

Comment: You may want to rethink your deployment strategy. I wouldn't want to run this line on each server, but perhaps create the working configs on a remote file server and have each server pull them after setup running a `post-install.sh` script. In this way you could add/edit more scripts in the future and just re-run setup script. Just a thought...

Comment: This is a plan we are working on for the future, but as it stands we don't have a spare server that we can use for our department at the moment. In the future we are looking towards solutions of exactly this nature, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah it all depends on your system size, I used to manage small amount of servers this way but when that number grew I used Jenkins to deploy things which isn't it's main purpose but it worked great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command.

```
sed -i "s/--class os/--class os --unrestricted/" filename
```

This will replace the line in the file without requiring a temp file, due to the -i option.

If it doesn't matter where in the line the "--unrestricted goes", this might be simpler.

```
sed -i "s/'Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu' --unrestricted/" filename
```

Comment: There are almost certainly more elegant solutions than what I've used here but this is a good beginner-style approach to using sed to solve issues like this. If you have other lines  in the file that contain "--class os", you'll need to expand the sed to include a part unique to that line.

Comment: Definitely great, thank you. so when we search with sed, it will replace what we search for always? So we need to include what we searched for in the inserted txt as well? That's something else I didn't know from the 5 or so sed articles I read.

Comment: Brendan, there are ways to search for strings but not replace them in regex. They are called look-ahead or look-behind groups. However, they are quite a bit more complicated. However, they don't work with sed.

Comment: Also, just tested it in a random desktop file with the above line of text in it, and it worked perfectly, thank you. Marked as an answer since you were first, despite Charles also being helpful.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is similar to RaidPinata's:

```
sudo sed -i s'/--class os \$menu/--class os --unrestricted \$menu/' /etc/default/grub
```

the "\$" escapes the "$" symbol so that it is not mis-inprepreted and I'm specifying a longer string so that if the command is executed twice, you don't get the insertion twice.

Comment: RaidPinata used double quotes and you used single quotes, does that matter here at all?

Comment: @Brendan77222 `sed` allows you to define the delimiters starting and ending the 's' command on the fly - RaidPinata used "/ and I used '/  ...  There are some differences in behavior using " instead of '.  I'm afraid I'm still learning as I go, so I'm not going to be much help past that!

Comment: Thank you for that, as well as the example of how to expand it. I definitely will need to and learning a new escape character will help me with that moving forward. I do believe I will need to expand frontwards rather than afterward due to the lines in the file being more similar after --class os. But this showed me exactly what was meant, thank you.

Comment: @Brendan77222 Where it matters most readily is if the string you are searching for uses either of those delimiters. As you see in my answer, using the " I can search for a string that has ' in it.

Comment: @Brendan77222 Here is a decent tutorial on quoting and meta-characters [https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html)

Comment: My quick question here considering I would need to include 'Ubuntu' in my search would be whether or not the double quotes would allow me to include single quotes inside them without an escape character.

Comment: @Brendan77222 - yes, that is what I did in the second command in my answer. It is the simplest way to search for something with single quotes to use the double quote as the outside delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

As @oldfred mention in his comment. My answer is, DO NOT DO THIS.

I'm not a professional, but I'm fairly certain each time the kernel is updated your grub is updated and any changes to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will be overwritten.

You want to likely create a custom Grub Entry and also if security is your concern this article seems to be a good read and have better options.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords#Protecting_Menuentries

Note: "Another option is to create a custom menu, add the menu items you wish (including those you want to protect), and disable the standard scripts. The users and passwords can be included in this file rather than in the 00_header file. This may be an easier method of assigning password protection - especially if only some of the menu items will be protected."

This is how I would add a custom menu entry to Grub2 but I have never made a custom entry for the existing OS so I leave that to you to research.

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom && sudo update-grub2

 menuentry "Ubuntu ISO" {
        set isofile="/home/isos/ubuntu.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject toram
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Comment: I have changed to editing the proper file that will keep it updated everytime. I am glad that he pointed it out. Thank you for the awesome links!